# Is there any way to make more than one `Box` pointing to the same heap memory?

Tags: rust

It seems like `Box.clone()` copies the heap memory. As I know, `Box` will get destructed after it gets out of its scope, as well as the memory area it is pointing to.

So I'd like to ask a way to create more than one `Box` object pointing to the same memory area.

Comment: It is possible, using unsafe code. However, when both boxes get dropped you will have a double free. Is that your intended use case? Our are you looking for reference counted pointers?

Comment: @aochagavia: Before that, you get aliasing violations... which completely upend Rust's safety.

Comment: Yay, every day I discover new beauties around UB

Comment: @aochagavia the last one~ I know it is not safe now. I'll use `Rc` and `Refcell` instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By definition, **you shall not**.

`Box` is explicitly created with the assumption that it is the sole owner of the object inside.

---

When multiple owners are required, you can use instead [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), those are reference-counted owners and the object will only be dropped when the last owner is destroyed.

Note, however, that they are not without downsides:

- the contained object cannot be mutated without runtime checks; if mutation is needed this requires using `Cell`, `RefCell` or some `Mutex` for example,
- it is possible to accidentally form cycles of objects, and since Rust has no Garbage Collector such cycles will be leaked.

Comment: I'll use `Rc` and `RefCell` instead of `Box` now. Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from a C++ background, consider that `Box` is Rust's implementation of a `std::unique_ptr`.

A `std::unique_ptr` is, by design, not copyable using either a copy constructor or an assignment operator.

It is however movable.

`Box` in Rust is the same, except that Rust is a move by default language, whereas C++ is copy by default.